# elements attributes return "undefined" for no reason

Tags: javascript, html

i have this piece of code:

```
function RemoveFromCart(id)
{

    var items = document.getElementById("overview").children;

    for(var i = 0; i < items.length;i++)
    {
        console.log(items[i]);
        console.log(items[i].value);
    }
}
```

the first log returns the actual element:

```
<div class="overview-item" value="0" data-total="5">1X item name - 5€<button onclick="RemoveFromCart(0)"></button></div>
```

but the second log returns

```
undefined
```

why is it doing this? 
why isn't it returning the value of the elements "value" attribute?
and how do i go about fixing it?

Comment: what is the console.log of items[i] ??

Comment: @chiragsatapara thats the first log

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<div>` element nodes don't have a "value" property. That's only for `<input>` and other form controls. If you put a "value" attribute in the tag, you have to use .getAttribute() to fetch the value.

Depending on what you're trying to do, you can inspect the children elements and check the "nodeType" property so you know what/how to access stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You are already using `data-*` attribute at `data-total="5"`, as pointed out by @Pointy `<div>` elements do not have a `.value` property. You can substitute `data-value="0"` for `value="0"` and use `HTMLElement.dataset` to get or set the value.

```
console.log(items[i].dataset.value);
```